# Best database structure for multiple value attributes

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL and I currently have 2 models.

1. `Users` (user_id, user_name),
2. `Players` (player_id, player_title, player_description)

I want to add the feature for users to add characteristics to players and other users. I was thinking to make a new table called `Characteristics` (characteristic_id, characteristic_description, user_id, player_id).

Each user can add multiple characteristics to multiple players. I read that adding multiple values to 1 row is not optimal for databases so my second option is to have multiple characteristics stored within the `Characteristics` table. But still I find this redundant because the values are being repeated.

Is there a better way to structure my database?

Example:

The `Characteristics` table might look like this:

```
characteristic_id     characteristic_description     user_id     player_id
1                     good                           1           1
2                     bad                            1           2
1                     good                           2           1
1                     good                           2           2
```

I find this redundant. Is there a better way? I also don't know how to add the feature for users to add characteristics to other users.

Thanks

Comment: IN addition to the Characteristics table, add a PlayerCharacteristics *join-table* listing the characteristics for each player.

Comment: thanks i will look into that. You have also a suggestion about adding characteristics to users? what is the best way?

Comment: This **is** the best and only proper way to do this in a relational world. First normal form of database design clearly states there must not ever be any attributes that can have multiple values - this is not relational anymore.

Comment: Hi marc_s, which way is proper my example or Pieter's suggestion?